# Do I need a 55++ battery to use a 27++ battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, thinkpad

I just recently received a 9 cell 27++ battery for my T510. I've never seen this kind before - it attaches to the bottom of the laptop. If I try to use it instead of a 55++ battery, the laptop receives no power.

Do I have to have both batteries in place for it to work? (I don't have both, so I wasn't able to try this myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A 27++ battery is a "slice" battery for extending the laptop's life beyond the 55++ already installed.